# What are the consequences of having a name on a European joint resolution?

Tags: law, european-union, parliament

I'd like to know what is the meaning of the names in the European joint resolutions such us [this one](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT%20MOTION%20P8-RC-2016-1346%200%20DOC%20XML%20V0//EN&language=en). Cristian Dan Preda, Elmar Brok... and many other EU politcians seem to have signed this document. But what are really the consequences of such signature?

Are they rather:

- Declarations of agreement with the resolution?
- Resolutions of how the next conduct by the EU executive regarding to the issue will proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you link to is not a joint resolution, but *a motion to a joint resolution*.

All the issues (laws, resolutions, etc.) discussed by the European Parliament must be introduced to it following a procedure, and will be assigned for the order of the day of a (or several) specific sessions. This grants EMP time to know and study the issues being proposed.

One of the procedures to get a resolution discused and voted by the Parliament is to get a number of MP to present a motion supporting the resolution; these are the names that you see in the linked page.

In this case it seems that several competing motions over the same issue were presented before by several political groups, and that this one has been negotiated between the MP to provide a text acceptable to all; this would explain the large number of MP (who match the MP who proposed the others motions, it would not be acceptable for a motion to "replace" another unless most of the MP presenting the original did agree to the new motion).

For example, the list of members of PPE Group listed is:

> Pier Antonio Panzeri, Jo Leinen, Victor Boştinaru, Knut Fleckenstein, Josef Weidenholzer, Clara Eugenia Aguilera García, Eric Andrieu, Zigmantas Balčytis, Hugues Bayet, Brando Benifei, Vilija Blinkevičiūtė, Soledad Cabezón Ruiz, Andrea Cozzolino, Andi Cristea, Isabella De Monte, Doru-Claudian Frunzulică, Elena Gentile, Lidia Joanna Geringer de Oedenberg, Neena Gill, Ana Gomes, Theresa Griffin, Sylvie Guillaume, Cătălin Sorin Ivan, Liisa Jaakonsaari, Afzal Khan, Jeppe Kofod, Cécile Kashetu Kyenge, Arne Lietz, Krystyna Łybacka, David Martin, Costas Mavrides, Alex Mayer, Sorin Moisă, Alessia Maria Mosca, Victor Negrescu, Momchil Nekov, Demetris Papadakis, Liliana Rodrigues, Daciana Octavia Sârbu, Monika Smolková, Tibor Szanyi, Claudia Țapardel, Marc Tarabella, Julie Ward, Damiano Zoffoli, Carlos Zorrinho on behalf of the S&D Group

and [in the (replaced) motion B8-2016-1361](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?type=MOTION&reference=B8-2016-1361&language=EN) by the S&D Group, they are:

> Pier Antonio Panzeri, Jo Leinen, Victor Boştinaru, Knut Fleckenstein, Josef Weidenholzer, Elena Valenciano, Clara Eugenia Aguilera García, Eric Andrieu, Zigmantas Balčytis, Hugues Bayet, Brando Benifei, José Blanco López, Vilija Blinkevičiūtė, Biljana Borzan, Soledad Cabezón Ruiz, Nicola Caputo, Andrea Cozzolino, Jonás Fernández, Monika Flašíková Beňová, Doru-Claudian Frunzulică, Eider Gardiazabal Rubial, Enrico Gasbarra, Lidia Joanna Geringer de Oedenberg, Neena Gill, Ana Gomes, Theresa Griffin, Sergio Gutiérrez Prieto, Cătălin Sorin Ivan, Liisa Jaakonsaari, Afzal Khan, Arne Lietz, Krystyna Łybacka, Costas Mavrides, Marlene Mizzi, Sorin Moisă, Victor Negrescu, Norbert Neuser, Demetris Papadakis, Pina Picierno, Kati Piri, Soraya Post, Inmaculada Rodríguez-Piñero Fernández, Daciana Octavia Sârbu, Siôn Simon, Tibor Szanyi, Claudia Țapardel, Marc Tarabella, Julie Ward, Damiano Zoffoli, Carlos Zorrinho on behalf of the S&D Group